# Angular 6, httpclient 404 error. GET URL getting automatically changed

Tags: angular

I have a very strange error. Spent hours trying to fix it, but still no clue. 
I will explain a very basic version of the problem i am having.
I have a simple angular page, calling a REST service on init, the returned data will be used to fill some menu options..

Below code works fine.

```
ngOnInit() {
    //this.Envi.BaseLink + `api/V2Startup?userid=${this.Envi.Userid}`

    this.http.get('http://dagilitywebv2/api/V2Startup?userid=TES0049').pipe(

    map((data: any) => ({
        Locations: data.Locations,
        MenuItems: (<any[]>data.Menu).map(mnu => ({ GroupName: mnu.GroupName, MenuList: mnu.MenuList, ExpandTree: true }))
        })),

  ).subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.Locations = data.Locations;
          this.MenuItems = data.MenuItems;
  });

 }
```

But if I replace the hard coded URL with

```
this.Envi.BaseLink + `api/V2Startup?userid=${this.Envi.Userid}`
```

I get a 404 error. Initially my impression was **this.Envi.BaseLink** did not have the right value so I did a console.log,

```
console.log(this.Envi.BaseLink + `api/V2Startup?userid=${this.Envi.Userid}`);
this.http.get(this.Envi.BaseLink + `api/V2Startup?userid=${this.Envi.Userid}`).pipe
```

Below is what I see. console.log printed the correct URL. But **to my $http.get** the dev domain of my site is getting added, i.e. **it is treating the address as relative to my root**.
[image]

1. http://dangularv6 is where my angular page is.
2. http://dagilitywebv2/api/V2Startup?userid=TES0049 is service I am trying to call.
3. But when **this.http.get** is getting called. Some how it is making a call to 
   http://dangularv6/dagilitywebV2//api/V2Startup?userid=TES0049, i.e. it is treating it as relative URL.
4. If I hard code again with http://dagilitywebv2/api/V2Startup?userid=TES0049 it works fine.

This same code works fine when i run my angular app locally (localport:4200), But when i move it to dev server to run under http://dangularv6, $http.get adds this prefix to my service URL.

I have no clue why it is happening.. any help?

**UPDATE:**
environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
production: false,
baselink: 'http://dagilitywebv2.lkq.lkqx.net/',
};
```

Injectable class

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class UserEnvironment {
    constructor() {this.BaseLink = environment.baselink;}
}
```

In component

```
import { UserEnvironment } from '../app-constants';
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private Envi: UserEnvironment) { }
```

Comment: What does it print when you do `console.log(this.Envi.BaseLink)`?

Comment: you are getting // before api, try http.get( `${this.Envi.BaseLink}api/V2Startup?userid=${this.Envi.Userid}.pipe(...)

Comment: http://dagilitywebv2/api/V2Startup?userid=TES0049 as it should be.,(highlighted in yellow in my screen shot)

Comment: is it maybe the base-href? Is the angular app deployed in the root folder or in a subfolder?

Comment: what about your environment.ts ? Where is defined `Envi.baseLink` ? and another vote for base-href

Comment: @TJK have you try `http://dagilitywebV2.lkq.lkqx.net/api/V2startup?userid=SAT0049`. instead `http://dagilitywebV2.lkq.lkqx.net//api/V2startup?userid=SAT0049` i think you remove one `/` from url

Comment: @fransyozef <head><base href="/">. app (index.html) is in root folder d:\inetpub\angularv6 to be exact.

Comment: @dun32 I updated question to include how I am reading BaseLink from environment.ts

Comment: @Abhishek started with http://dagilitywebV2.lkq.lkqx.net/api/V2startup?userid=SAT0049 then changed my code to this.BaseLink + '/api..' , I was just playing around to see if this helps. Sadly none.

Answer (score 0):

Your Envi Baselink must be broken, since the get is trying to go to `http://dangularv6/dagilitywebv2//`

Maybe you need a BaseUrl for your client and another one for your server in your Envi so you can use instead of only BaseUrl, a BaseUrl in some cases, and ServerUrl in others

I might be wrong though

Comment: But if I print Envi Baselink to console, I am getting http://dagilitywebv2/api/V2Startup?userid=TES0049

Comment: I know but the error get tries to fetch from another dir. So maybe it's something on the service that already adds a BaseUrl to your calls on every call (an interceptor?) or another thing adding the dangularv6 part to your url..

Attempt a global search (ctrl + f usually) for 'dangularv6' to see if you can find a place where this particular string is getting added to your get http request

Comment: I created this application only with this page (to debug this problem).
I did not create any interceptor (unless there is one by default, which i am not able to figure out). I also it a search on dangularv6 and it is not there (very unlikely it will be there, since again i created this only for testing purpose)